# Search for particular results with a certain string in GraphQL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, graphql, apollo

I want to search with my query `getFoodType` to return results based on whether the `foodType` of particular restaurant/takeaway is a `"Chicken","Pizza"` etc

Like this `foodType: "Chicken"`

I've tried using arguments and mongoDB filters (it's a MongoDB server) but no luck.

`Schema`

```
const EaterySchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  address: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  foodType: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});
```

My Schema Types

```
  type Eatery {
    id: String!
    name: String!
    address: String!
    foodType: String!
  }
  type Query {
    eatery(id: String!): Eatery
    eateries: [Eatery]
    getFoodType(foodType: String): [Eatery]
  }
```

My `Resolver`

```
    getFoodType: () => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Eatery.find({})
          .populate()
          .exec((err, res) => {
            err ? reject(err) : resolve(res);
          });
      });
    },
```

Current Query in Apollo Playground

```
{
   getFoodType (foodType: "Chicken") {
     id
     name
     address
     foodType
   }
 }
```

I essentially want to return all the results with "Chicken" as a the `foodType`. Something like `foodType: "Chicken"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to get the value of the `foodType` to be queried in `Resolver`

```js
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    getFoodType: (_, args) => {
      const { foodType } = args
      ...
    },
  },
}
```

Then use `foodType` when querying

```js
Eatery.find({ foodType })
```

Finally need to return the result

```js
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  return Eatery.find({ foodType })
    .populate()
    .exec((err, res) => {
      err ? reject(err) : resolve(res)
    })
})
```

Complete example

```js
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    getFoodType: (_, args) => {
      const { foodType } = args
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        return Eatery.find({ foodType })
          .populate()
          .exec((err, res) => {
            err ? reject(err) : resolve(res)
          })
      })
    },
  },
}
```

Use the `async/await`

```js
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    getFoodType: async (_, { foodType }) => {
      try {
        const eaterys = await Eatery.find({ foodType }).populate()
        return eaterys
      } catch (e) {
        // Handling errors
      }
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: That worked beautifully @XYShaoKang it's returning all the eateries with that foodType thank you!

Just out of interest, why use a GQL **Mutation** instead of a **Query**?

Comment: This is my mistake and should use `Query` :sweat_smile:

Comment: Awesome dude! Also If you have time I'd just change the above `footType` to `foodType`.

Comment: Sorry, my English is not a native language, so I am not very sensitive to the wrong words. I have not checked them carefully. I have corrected them .